# Get "Show as" for an appointment in EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Ive been looking at adding some basic Exchange functionality to our intranet, and so far it all seems fairly easy to do. 
However, Ive run into a small issue I dont know how to solve.

I am displaying our users calendars on their profile page but I also need to show the "Show as" attribute for each appointment entry.
This is where Im coming up short. Looking at the Appointment properties there is nothing that seems to do the trick. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment_properties%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Can any of you guys point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you looking for is the LegacyFreeBusyStatus [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.legacyfreebusystatus(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.legacyfreebusystatus%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) which in the way EWS represents the ShowAs setting on an appointment. eg

```
        CalendarView cv = new CalendarView(DateTime.Now,DateTime.Now.AddDays(200),100);
        FindItemsResults<Appointment>findresults = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, cv);

        foreach (Appointment aptval in findresults.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(aptval.LegacyFreeBusyStatus);        
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Should I be concerned that this field is named "Legacy".  Is this still the right way to mark an Appointment as free time?

Comment: To access that property you first have to call Appointment.Load(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties), or maybe retrieve that property specifically.

Comment: @k2col Did you ever find out the answer to that question? It's looking like i have no choice but to use this method.

Comment: @DickieBoy - I didn't but I agree with you it seems we have no choice... I am using LegacyFreeBusyStatus in my app and it's working as expected.